# Unable to create a mapbox mapview with styleURL

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I would like to create a map view with a different style, such as [MapBox Dark](https://www.mapbox.com/studio/styles/mapbox/dark-v9/). However I couldn't get anything but a white blank view with the mapbox logo at the bottom (please see the attached picture)

Which part is wrong in my code?

```
import UIKit
import Mapbox

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var mapView: MGLMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let styleDarkURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v9")
        mapView = MGLMapView(frame: view.bounds, styleURL: styleDarkURL)
        mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        view.addSubview(mapView)

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you added your Mapbox key into your info.plist?

Comment: @Magnas I did add the key

Comment: Try replacing URL(fileURLWithPath: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v9") with URL(string: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v9")

Comment: @Magnas Yes problem solved! can you please add it to the answer? So I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace your

```
URL(fileURLWithPath: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v9")
```

with

```
URL(string: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v9")
```

Hope this helps.